# ADF not adding new column to sink SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have changed the mapping of a sink in ADF. I have added a new column in the output of the sink stage.

The sink is connected to an SQL DB, now when the insert is going through, the new column is not added to the sql data table.

Strangely, no error is thrown as well.

Comment: You cannot create a new column in the existing table through mapping activity. You can only map to the existing fields in copy activity.

Comment: This is an excepted behavior when your Azure Data Explorer dataset was created long time before so that it is still using our old dataset model which is not supported by Additional Columns. To resolve this issue, you can just follow the error message to create a new ADX dataset and use this as copy sink. For more details please follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy)

Answer (score 0):

When you change the schema of the sink by adding a new column, you need to ensure that the new column is mapped to the correct source data in the mapping. If the schema of the sink does not match the schema of the data being written, the data may not be written to the sink, resulting in missing data while copying.

In this case, once you add a new column in the destination table, you can also add the same in the mapping.

- Click `+ New mapping` in the mapping tab and provide the source and sink columns.

[image]

- Once the mapping is changed, all new records will be inserted with data in the additional new column in the sink.